# Link_to Routing Issue With Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, nested-resources

I have two models Jobs and Questions. A job has many questions and questions belong to a job. 
I've set up the resources in the model, as well as the routes. I am having an issue trying to link_to the Show method of the questions controller on the questions#index page. My rake routes say that the path should be job_question_path with the two necessary :id's being :job_id and :id , so I tried:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', job_question_path(@job, question) %></td>
```

and got the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"questions", :job_id=>nil, :id=>#<Question id: 1, job_id: 1, question1: "sfsdfssfs", question2: "sfsdfs", question3: "sfsdf", question4: "sfsdfsf", question5: "sfsfsfs", created_at: "2011-06-21 03:25:12", updated_at: "2011-06-21 03:25:12">}
```

I've tried multiple other combos and nothing is seeming to work, I keep getting:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"questions", :job_id=>nil }
```

or some combination of that.

The part I don't get is that I can put in the url /jobs/1/questions/1 and it takes me to the show page, so I am assuming that my questions#show methods are ok. See below for the rest of my code.

Questions#index view

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= question.question1 %></td>
  <td><%= question.question2 %></td>
  <td><%= question.question3 %></td>
  <td><%= question.question4 %></td>
  <td><%= question.question5 %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', job_question_path(@job, question) %></td>
</tr>
```

<% end %>

Questions Controller

```
def index
 @questions = Question.all

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @questions }
 end
end

def show
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @question = @job.questions.find(params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @question }
 end
end
```

Models

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :questions

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
```

Routes.rb

```
 root :to => "pages#home"

 resources :jobs do
  resources :questions
 end

 get "pages/home"
 get "pages/about"
 get "pages/contact"
```

See this https://gist.github.com/1032734 for my rake routes.

Thanks for any help in advance, i've been at this for a while now and just can't figure out the solution. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be so?

Questions#index view

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= question.question1 %></td>
  <td><%= question.question2 %></td>
  <td><%= question.question3 %></td>
  <td><%= question.question4 %></td>
  <td><%= question.question5 %></td>
  <%= link_to 'Show', job_question_path(question.job_id, question.id) %>
</tr>
```

It have to work. Or haven't you 'job_id' field in Questions table ?

Comment: That didn't work, I am getting  `undefined method 'job_id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: There it is, I had messed around with the index action but after breaking it, put it back to it original state.

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Show', job_question_path(question.job_id, question.id) %>` - That is it , it worked! Thanks! I think I understand why too!

Comment: i say it from beginning)) Read books, because you write not very nice code. Good Luck. Rails is the BEST.