# Nesting Resources 3 Levels Deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, nested-resources

I have an idea of what is going wrong, but am having trouble fixing it.

To explain my situation again, I have 3 elements : Jobs, Questions and Answers . All of the relationships are set up below. Expanding on my previous question which had to do with Jobs > Questions relationship, I have now added the  Answers relationship in Jobs > Questions > Answers.

So, with a new resource in my routes.rb I was getting routing errors, which I was fixing as I was going. The problem occurred when I got to the form Answers#new page and had to modify the form_for scaffolding and build on the **Create** action in the Answers controller ( you can see my code for those two below).

I was able to fix those enough to show the form on the new answers page, but when I click submit I am getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"answers", :job_id=>nil, :question_id=>1, :id=>#<Answer id: 3, job_id: nil, question_id: 1, answer1: "", answer2: "", answer3: "", answer4: "", answer5: "", created_at: "2011-07-01 03:12:06", updated_at: "2011-07-01 03:12:06">}
```

From this error I can see that I am not saving the job_id and I am pretty sure this has to do with me not calling the job_id properly in either my answers create action or answers new form_for code. I've tried a ton of solutions, but nothing seems to work. I feel like I am close on my create action, but can't get it right. Anyways, thanks in advance for any help and if I haven't provided you without enough surrounding code, let me know and I will add it.

This question is an extenstion of this post: [Link_to Routing Issue With Nested Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421078/link-to-routing-issue-with-nested-resources)

P.S. I also added my answers show action, because although it is working properly if I go to the answers/1/ directly. I just have a feeling that if my create action is wrong, so is my show action.

Models:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :questions
has_many :answers

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :job
has_many :answers

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :job
belongs_to :question
```

Answers#new Form

```
<%= form_for(@answer, :url => job_question_answers_path(@answer.job_id, @question)) do |f| %>
```

Answers create action

```
def create
@job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
@question = @job.questions.find(params[:question_id])
@answer = @question.answers.build(params[:answer])
if @answer.save
 redirect_to(job_question_answer_path(@answer.job_id, @answer.question_id, @answer)
end
end
```

Answers show action

```
def show
 @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
 @question = @job.questions.find(params[:question_id])
 @answer = @question.answers.find(params[:id])
end
```

See this https://gist.github.com/1057810 for my most current rake routes. I know I shouldn't nest more than 1 layer deep, but it was the easiest and quickest solution for me.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this line:

```
No route matches {
  :action=>"show", :controller=>"answers", 
  :job_id=>nil, #Problem
  :question_id=>1, 
  :id=>#<Answer id: 3, job_id: nil, question_id: 1, answer1: "", answer2: "", answer3: "", answer4: "", answer5: "", created_at: "2011-07-01 03:12:06", updated_at: "2011-07-01 03:12:06">}
```

You can see that the `job_id` in your Answer object is nil.  Your form helper uses `job_question_answers_path` which requires a `job_id` and a `question_id`, but the route error is broken because the `job_id` is nil (`@answer.job_id`):

```
<%= form_for(@answer, :url => job_question_answers_path(@answer.job_id, @question)) do |f| %>
```

Try setting `@answer.job` in your `AnswersController#new` action explicitly.

```
def new
  # You may already have code that does this...
  @answer = Answer.new

  # Guessing on param names here:
  @answer.question = Question.find params[:question_id]
  @answer.job = Job.find params[:job_id]

  # Alternatively, you can probably just set the ids, 
  # but the above will verify those objects exist first.
  @answer.job_id = params[:job_id]
  @answer.question_id = params[:question_id]
end
```

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks for the help and explaining it all. Unfortunately, I added that code to my answers new action and it is still not properly saving the job_id through the same error- `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"answers", :job_id=>nil, :question_id=>1, :id=>#<Answer id: 1, job_id: nil, question_id: 1, answer1: "dfgdg", answer2: "dfgdg", answer3: "dfgdg", answer4: "dgd", answer5: "dgd", created_at: "2011-07-05 22:43:15", updated_at: "2011-07-05 22:43:15">}`.Does this mean that it has to be a create answers issue? Here's a pastie of the server- http://www.pastie.org/2169613